# FQL query for photos returns photos from hidden (blocked) users. How to prevent this?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I request latest photos for a user using an FQL query, like the one below:
SELECT pid, aid, owner, src_small, src_big, src, link, caption, created FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=) ORDER BY modified_major DESC LIMIT 300) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 500

It works well but I believe it doesn't respect the setting where the user block specific users on the facebook page. So in my app, he sees all the photos, and he's not happy :).

Now, I see that in user table there's is_blocked property, but it's not indexed so I can't use it in a WHERE clause. I also don't want to call FB for every user I get just to check for that property and filter based on that in the app itself.

So, first of all, am I correct that this query doesn't respect blocked users settings?
If yes, is there a way to respect this setting using FQL?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [privacy table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/). There is `id` column which represent an image object as well and `deny` field with a list of users that cannot see the object. I think you should use a fql.multi-query to resolve this. Some info about fql.multi-query you can find at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814486/new-fql-multiquery-in-graph-api-javascript-example).