# New FQL Multiquery in Graph API Javascript Example?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Anyone had luck with doing multiquery through javascript API or ajax?

Comment: I'd say that was a unanimous no! haha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have successfully done this, although I had a bit of trouble at first with the documentation only having a php example.

Just make sure you are attaching the `queries` json as the 2nd parameter in the api call rather than as a query string like in the php sample. That is:

```
FB.api('/fql', {q:{"query1":"SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=12345678","query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"}}, 
function(response) {
    // handle response
});
```

Comment: AH, thanks for your help.  That was not very clear with the PHP example, you're right.

Comment: Nice one! It's amazing this stuff isn't in the documentation.